# How can I replace the Value property of the Progressbar when inheriting it?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to create a custom UserControl control that inherits the ProgressBar class.  I want to try to replace the "Value" property of the ProgressBar class.  When I try and do that I get stuck in an infinite loop because trying to set the Value property ends up calling my new class property instead.

So the question is, is there any way around this or will I need to create some type of internal variables to keep track of the Value of the progressbar?  How would that work?

Here is what I have so far...

```
public partial class MyProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
        public new int Value
        {
            get { return Value; }
            set
            {
                if (value < Minimum) value = Minimum;
                if (value > Maximum) value = Maximum;
                Value = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can use "base.Value" to refer to the property in the base class from the subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class MyProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
        public new int Value
        {
            get { return base.Value; }
            set
            {
                if (value < Minimum) value = Minimum;
                if (value > Maximum) value = Maximum;
                base.Value = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for!  I knew it would be simple, I use base all the time!  I guess I just needed it pointed out for me.  It there was not a throttle on how fast one could accept an answer this would already be checked as the accepted answer.  ;)